# How can I show elapsed time in Django

Tags: django

So, I'm trying to show elapsed time on a page for recent-visited history. On my model, I have the following attribute.

**models.py**

```
class History(models.Model):
    ...
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ...
```

I already checked [the date documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#date), but it doesn't have a way to represent elapsed time from creating time to now. Doesn't Django support the feature? then should I implement it on my own?

Comment: Could you specify do you want to display elapsed time or time difference like [timesince](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know Django doesn't have such function. It's better to implement your own.  With `js` for instance by using `setInterval()` and `Ajax` to update a specific time field.

Before that, you need to add a field to record when leaving the page.

```
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
left_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Js**
It's important that you have this script in your HTML page, since we'll use Django variables.

```
var id_obj = '{{ obj.id }}'; // $('tag').val();
totalSeconds = 5;
setInterval(function(){
     recordElapsedTime();
},totalSeconds * 1000);

var recordElapsedTime = function(){
    $.ajax({
         url:"/url/to/view/",
         type:"POST",
         data:{
             id_obj:id_obj,
             csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}'
         },
    });
}
```

**View**

```
 import datetime

 def elapsedTime(request):
     if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
         id_obj = request.POST.get('id_obj')
         obj = get_object_or_404(ObjectModel,id=id_obj)
         obj.left_at = datetime.datetime.now()
         obj.save()
```

Now it's pretty easy to determine the elapsed time, as a property method in Model for instance.

```
@property
def elapsed_time(self)
    return (self.left_at - self.created_on).seconds
```